# Android - Navigation Drawer change action bar icon

Tags: android, navigation, icons, action, drawer

I have action bar with one icon:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/is_connected"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_disconnected"
    android:title="@string/general_disconnected"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

When I change that icon in this way:

```
mActionBarMenu.getItem(0).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_connected));
```

and open navigation drawer that that item icon change to initial state ang again is: `@drawable/ic_disconnected`

It is possible to avoid that?

**UPDATE:**

```
    private void setupDrawer() {
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.navList);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();

    addDrawerItem();

    mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    mActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            //getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Menu");
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };

    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });

    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}
```

Comment: Are you using an `ActionBarDrawerToggle`?

Comment: @MikeM. yes, i'm using ActionBarDrawerToggle. Please look on my next post below

Comment: It's the calls to `invalidateOptionsMenu()` that are causing that. If you don't need them, you can remove them.